# How to store cache in cefsharp version 79

Tags: cefsharp

I am using cefsharp in my Winform application. I try to store cookies, cache... so that I do not have to login a web site each time I run my application.
I try to implement as follows:

```
Dim requestContextSettings = New RequestContextSettings()
requestContextSettings.CachePath = Application.StartupPath + "\Resources"
_browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://cookies_enabled_web.com", New RequestContext(requestContextSettings, New CustomRequestContextHandler()))
```

Then I implement the class

```
Public Class CustomRequestContextHandler
Implements IRequestContextHandler

Public Sub OnRequestContextInitialized(requestContext As IRequestContext) Implements IRequestContextHandler.OnRequestContextInitialized
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Function OnBeforePluginLoad(mimeType As String, url As String, isMainFrame As Boolean, topOriginUrl As String, pluginInfo As WebPluginInfo, ByRef pluginPolicy As PluginPolicy) As Boolean Implements IRequestContextHandler.OnBeforePluginLoad
    Return True
End Function

Public Function GetResourceRequestHandler(browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, request As IRequest, isNavigation As Boolean, isDownload As Boolean, requestInitiator As String, ByRef disableDefaultHandling As Boolean) As IResourceRequestHandler Implements IRequestContextHandler.GetResourceRequestHandler
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

End Class

But it does not work as expected?
Does anyone know how to fix the problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure you've read the documentation http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_RequestContextSettings_CachePath.htm

Comment: Thank you. I have read the document and found the clues.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have successfully stored cache data in Cefsharp version 79. I execute the following code before create the instance of browser.

```
 Dim setting As New CefSettings()
setting.CachePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resources")
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(setting)
```